# Troubleshooting Crystal Reports file after MRP upgrade

Tags: sql, crystal-reports, odbc

We recently upgrade our MRP from JobBoss 2018 to JobBoss 2020.  We have a few custom reports, but one certain report is giving us major headaches, and it is the most customized report with several sub reports.  By default it uses a TTX for database, but we have added an ODBC connection to the SQL database.

"Now certain pack list our reporting an error: Invalid Argument provided.  Invalid argument in the database."

This error only happens with certain pack lists.  I have hacked the RPT file and removed a couple group selections and most of the subreports and the error goes away, but then the report is worth nothing.

I need more feedback than this error message, but how?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this error had to do with the table linking in Crystal.  I had multiple starting links.  Still having problems with the amount of time the report is generating, but it works now.